# Please merge tag "extender" into "teleconverter"

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-naming

We have a number of questions tagged [extender](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/extender). This is what Canon calls their teleconverters; let's just merge the two tags.

Comment: Done, tags have been merged. Most of the 10 had TC on them already.